# 正規表現で全角スペースを禁止したい

Tags: php, 正規表現, laravel

今使っているのはこれです

```
regex:/^[ぁ-んァ-ヶー一-龠a-zA-Z0-9]+$/
```

半角スペースは不可になったが全角スペースは無理らしいですね。

Comment: `'/^[^　]+$/'` など。

Answer (score 2):

調べてみたのですが、phpの文字クラスで直接文字範囲を使用できるのはASCIIの範囲のみのようです。
Unicodeをuオプションで指定し正規表現を組むと良いそうなので、以下のように変更してみました。

質問に記載の範囲
`一-龠ぁ-んァ-ヶーa-zA-Z0-9`
`\x{4E00}-\x{9FA0}\x{3041}-\x{3093}\x{30A1}-\x{30F6}\x{30FC}a-zA-Z0-9`

（お好みで）常用漢字の範囲
`々〇〻㐀-鿿豈-﫿 0-⿿F`
`\x{3005}\x{3007}\x{303b}\x{3400}-\x{9FFF}\x{F900}-\x{FAFF}\x{20000}-\x{2FFFF}`

```
$regex='/^[\x{3005}\x{3007}\x{303b}\x{3400}-\x{9FFF}\x{F900}-\x{FAFF}\x{20000}-\x{2FFFF}\x{4E00}-\x{9FA0}\x{3041}-\x{3093}\x{30A1}-\x{30F6}\x{30FC}a-zA-Z0-9]+$/u';
preg_match($regex, $in, $out);
```